# How to create more than one instance with own copy of global variables

Tags: c++, embedded

I have two projects:

1. Embedded one, written in C++, which uses a lot of static/global variables.
2. Second one, running on PC and using the same source codes as embedded one uses.

It works very well.

But now second project should run more than one instances of embedded project. Furthermore each instance should have its own copy of static/global variables, and I should be able to interact with each instance in one program scope. I don't know how to do this with all that static/global variables.

Is there any simple way to solve my problem?

Comment: Get rid of the global variables.

Comment: I agree with Jocke - you will need to somehow rid your code of global variables in this case.

Comment: It's a very huge project with many static methods and static fields. It was made intentionally to simplify interaction between objects of program.

Comment: @dwelch: that is entirely not helping. You still have only one, and your program now probably fails to compile.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can solve this:

1. Spawn multiple processes (each with their own set of globals) and setup channels of communication between them and the main program.
2. Get rid of the global variables.  The easiest way to do this would be to dump them all in a class (as non-static members) and use instances of that class to access each set of variables.

Either way, it's not a small problem to solve if you have a large number of globals.

Comment: I would go with (2).  In the embedded code, just make one static 'Global' class instance in main().  On the PC, make as many as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Run two separate processes and use some form of IPC to communicate between the the processes.  In Windows IPC mechanisms available include:

- Clipboard
- COM
- Data Copy
- DDE
- File Mapping
- Mailslots
- Pipes
- RPC
- Windows Sockets

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details of each of these.  Similar mechanisms are available in other operating systems.

A perhaps simpler alternative is to run each instance in a separate thread and place the globals in [thread local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In all cases however, you should avoid nit just "a lot" but any global variables.  It is generally indicative of poor design.  See [this article](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) for why globals are bad, and ways to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state the best solution is to get rid of the globals, but I understand that this is not always feasible.
I ran into the exact same problem with our code base.

The solution I used was to build each instance as a separate DLL.
Then load I loaded each DLL with `LoadLibrary()` at runtime.
In this way you can get everything to run in a single process and have multiple version of the same globals and singletons.
And then you don't need to use any IPC but can pass data between the instances with a simple function call. It also makes the debugging easier, because you can see everything in one debugger.

NOTE: I made it on Windows, but I assume the something similar is possible on Unix.